# Value of b which moves quadratic from a stable fixed point to a stable period 2 point

Tags: numerical-methods, bifurcation

I have a question which asks:
At what value of b does the quadratic 1.5x^2+bx+2.34 move from having a stable fixed point to having a stable period 2 point? 
How would I go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are iterating $x_{i+1}=1.5x_i^2+bx_i+2.34$  You can find the fixed point by solving $x_{i+1}=x_i$, giving the quadratic $x=1.5x^2+bx+2.34$.  The fixed point will be a function of $b$.  It is stable if the derivative of $1.5x^2+bx+2.34$ evaluated at the fixed point has absolute value less than $1$.  This is because the slope of the curve is the factor the error is multiplied by each step.  If the absolute value is less than 1, you get closer.  If the absolute value is greater than 1, you get farther away.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help.
How do I solve for my value of b? I've tried playing around with it in derive and I can't get any positive value for b.

Comment: Alpha gives $x=-5-b\pm \sqrt{25(b-1)^2-351}$ which is real about when $b \gt 4.75$ or $b \lt -2.75$  This is the fixed point as a function of $b$.  Now take $\left| \frac {dx_{i+1}}{dx_i}\right |$ and plug in this value.

Comment: I'm very sorry, I've never seen Alpha used before, where did you get it from?

Comment: It is at http://www.wolframalpha.com/  It is quite useful

Comment: From Wolfram I can only seem to get x~~0.0666667 (-5. b+/-sqrt(25. b^2-50. b-326.)+5.)
That was for 1.5x^2+bx+2.34=x

Comment: Yes, I left off the $\frac 1{15}$ on that.  I was focused on the rest at the time.  The range of $b$ doesn't change, but the value of $x$ does

Comment: Okay, so using Derive I can get the values b>4.780211634 and b<-2.780211634, using the values for x. From here, how do I find my positive b to move it to a stable period 2 point? Thanks again.

Comment: As in my first comment, you need to take the derivative of $x_{i+1}$, then substitute in the fixed point expression, then find the $b$ that makes the slope equal to $1$.  That is the transition point.

Comment: So d/dx(1.5x^2+bx+2.34)=3x+b.
Then I set =1 and solve for b?

Comment: You now have two equations in two unknowns.  You have $3x+b=1$ (and you have to do $-1$ too) and the expression that came from solving the quadratic.  Solve them simultaneously.

Comment: I get my value as b= 5.412253527 but when I check it on Maple TA, it says the correct answer is 5.247352116.
Is there anything I could've done wrong?

Comment: Ignore me, I made a silly error, thank you for all your help